I got error with LayerZero Hello World Project
I tried to follow this cookbook but i got errors
https://docs.layerzero.network/cookbook/hello-oapp-hardhat
i this step npx hardhat lz:deploy
I got :
failed to get chainId, falling back on net_version...
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Network  bsctestnet                                  │
│ Error    TypeError: extenders is not iterable        │
└─────────-────────────────────────────────────────────┘


Hardhar.conf.js

// Get the environment configuration from .env file
//
// To make use of automatic environment setup:
// - Duplicate .env.example file and name it .env
// - Fill in the environment variables
import 'dotenv/config'

import 'hardhat-deploy'
import 'hardhat-contract-sizer'
import '@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers'
import '@layerzerolabs/toolbox-hardhat'
import { HardhatUserConfig, HttpNetworkAccountsUserConfig } from 'hardhat/types'

import { EndpointId } from '@layerzerolabs/lz-definitions'

// Set your preferred authentication method
//
// If you prefer using a mnemonic, set a MNEMONIC environment variable
// to a valid mnemonic
const MNEMONIC = process.env.MNEMONIC

// If you prefer to be authenticated using a private key, set a PRIVATE_KEY environment variable
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY

const accounts: HttpNetworkAccountsUserConfig | undefined = MNEMONIC
    ? { mnemonic: MNEMONIC }
    : PRIVATE_KEY
      ? [PRIVATE_KEY]
      : undefined

if (accounts == null) {
    console.warn(
        'Could not find MNEMONIC or PRIVATE_KEY environment variables. It will not be possible to execute transactions in your example.'
    )
}

console.log(EndpointId.BSC_TESTNET);

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
    paths: {
        cache: 'cache/hardhat',
    },
    solidity: {
        compilers: [
            {
                version: '0.8.24',
                settings: {
                    optimizer: {
                        enabled: true,
                        runs: 200,
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    networks: {
        sepolia: {
            eid: EndpointId.SEPOLIA_V2_TESTNET,
            url: 'https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/_iBKXjCAmRXcQM8AjMQ3m0tCAawf17F2',
            chainId: 11155111,
            accounts,
        },
        bsctestnet: {
            eid: EndpointId.BSC_V2_TESTNET,
            url: `https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/`, // BNB Testnet
            chainId: 97,
            accounts,
          },     
    },
    namedAccounts: {
        deployer: {
          default: 0,
        },
        feeWallet: {
          default: 1,
        },
        proposer: {
          default: 2,
        },
        executor: {
          default: 3,
        },
    },
}

export default config


layerzero.conf.js

import { EndpointId } from '@layerzerolabs/lz-definitions'

import type { OAppOmniGraphHardhat, OmniPointHardhat } from '@layerzerolabs/toolbox-hardhat'

const sepoliaContract: OmniPointHardhat = {
    eid: EndpointId.SEPOLIA_V2_TESTNET,
    contractName: 'MyOApp',
}

const bsctestnetContract: OmniPointHardhat = {
    eid: EndpointId.BSC_V2_TESTNET,
    contractName: 'MyOApp',
}

const config: OAppOmniGraphHardhat = {
    contracts: [
        {
            contract: sepoliaContract,
        },
        {
            contract: bsctestnetContract,
        },
    ],
    connections: [
        {
            from: sepoliaContract,
            to: bsctestnetContract,
        },
        {
            from: bsctestnetContract,
            to: sepoliaContract,
        },
    ],
}

export default config

Plz help !!!
Best regards

Downgrading your hardhat version to 2.22.9 or lower should fix this error.
